# Using resistor with 110 V LED indicator to make current measurement between 50 - 70 mA

Tags: resistors, circuit-design, parallel, current-limiting

I need your guidance with the V=IR formula. It's probably a simple question but I don't have an electrical background.

I am working on making an LED simulator panel for railway signaling interlocking to check the I/O of the signal lamp driving card.

The computer card that controls the signal LED has a current measuring functionality. The computer shuts down the card if the current value is <50 mA or >70 mA.

The small LED indicator for the simulator panel I found is 110 V with 6 mA max current. To bring the current value to between 50..70 mA, I am using a 1500 ohms resistance in parallel.

Any suggestions and will the circuit work?

Is there anything I should add to make it safe?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

110V/1500R=73mA , so it sounds like this resistor will put you over the high limit even without the LED.

Aiming for 60mA, and subtracting the indicators 6mA: 110V/0.054A=2037R

2.05K is the closest 1% resistor value to this.

The dissipation in the resistor will be 110V^2/2050R = **6W**.  So it's going to have to be a power resistor and it will get quite warm (just like the original light bulb would have).

Comment: thank you @drew

Answer (score 0):

You could try using a 2 μF or 2.2 μF capacitor instead of your 1500 Ω resistor. Its impedance will be about 1500 Ω but will have the advantage of close to zero power dissipation.

You can check using a [capacitor impedance calculator](https://www.allaboutcircuits.com/tools/capacitor-impedance-calculator/). My calculations were done for 50 Hz supply.

The capacitor rating will have to be > 100 V AC.